# Find the absolute max and min values of a multivariable function bounded by a circular boundary

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find the absolute minimum and maximum values of $f (x, y) = xy e^{−2x^2 −2y^2}$ on the set $\Delta = $ {$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2} | x^2+y^2\le1$}

i know i should take the partial derivatives and set them $=0$ however the constrains is there for a reason to examine the points at the edges of it right?

don't get me wrong i know how to deal with it if the constrain was a triangle or a square but when it is a circle i feel i am lost. Any help will be highly appreciated. Please be as detailed as you could, and any links to youtube videos would be just amazing.

Comment: The extrema are either of calculus type on the interior of the region, in which case you take partial derivatives and set them to zero, as you say, or else they occur on the boundary. When dealing with the boundary you are at least two options, first convert to polars when the minimisation/maximisation on the boundarey becomes an unconstrained minimisation/maximisation problem in one variable, or use the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: When you have a circular region, using polar coordinates is _often_ a good idea: the function becomes $$ \ f(r, \ \theta) \ = \ r^2 \ \cos \theta \ \sin \theta \ e^{-2r^2} \ \ = \ \  \frac{1}{2} \ r^2  \ \sin (2 \theta) \ e^{-2r^2} \ \ . $$  This tells you that the extrema will lie along the diagonal lines $  \ y \ = \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ = \ -x \ $ . _On_ the circle, you can set $ \ r \ = \ 1 \ $ .